# Stuck while executing cmd commands via C#

Tags: c#

I am writing a C# code that will call my windows cmd and execute commands on it but i am stuck in last statement because after executing "pscp" command , it asks for the "username's password" which i already have but donot know how my code can take care of it.

My Code sample :

```
const string cmdtext = @"/k cd\&pscp.exe&pscp C:\Users\user\Desktop\Backup\standalone-full.xml username@hostname:/apps/tempdir/express/standalone-full.xml"; 
Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe", cmdtext);                                        // after executing this command, it asks for the username's password
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: As i know you can passe user name and password as paramaters to pscp and it won't ask them interactively (http://www.nber.org/pscp.html)

Comment: You can use this overload of Process.Start http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxf2saat.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can try bitvise ssh client instead. You can put the password on the command line version of the tool.

btw, you should use powershell instead of C# for these tasks.

Answer (score -1):

i usually call pscp like this:

```
pscp -l <username> -pw <password> <options> <source> <host>:<target>
```

example:

```
pscp -l root -pw root C:\myfile.txt 192.168.0.1:/home/myfile.txt
```

that works without prompt

Comment: it works : pscp -pw root C:\myfile.txt username@192.168.0.1:/home/myfile.txt

Comment: Have you tried to use the overload `Process.Start(string fileName,string arguments)` to supply the arguments to the process? [Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx)